# Why is my sequelize model undefined only when I try to use find functions?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, passport-local

I'm trying to set up a user login and registration with the ORM Sequelize in Node. I have the registration part working fine. My model instance is defined as User, and when I call User.createUser, my model function works and a user is added to the db. However, when I try to use my getUserNameById function in my passport local strategy, I get an error "User is not defined". I've been stuck for over a day trying to figure this out.

Model file (I've imported sequelize, bcrypt, and created a connection)

```
var Users = connection.define("Users", {
    id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true,
    },
    name: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
    },
    username: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
    },
    account: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
    },
    email: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
    },
    password: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
    },

}, {
    timestamps: false 
});


Users.sync();

connection.authenticate()
    .then(function () {
        console.log("CONNECTED! ");
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        console.log("MYSQL ERROR: FAILED TO CONNECT");
    })
    .done();



module.exports = function (connection, DataTypes) {
    return Users; 
}


module.exports.createUser = function (newUser) {
    bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err, salt) {
        bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, salt, function(err, hash) {
            newUser.password = hash;
            Users.create(newUser).then(function (Users){
                console.dir(Users.get());
            })
        });
    }); 
}

module.exports.getUserByUsername = function (username) {
    return Users.find({
        where: {username: username}
    }).then(function (user) {}, function (err) {
            console.log(err);
    }); 
}


module.exports.comparePassword = function(candidatePassword, hash, done, user){
    bcrypt.compare(password, hash, function(err, isMatch){
        if (err) console.log(err)
        if (isMatch) {
            return done(null, user)
        } else {
            return done(null, false)
        }
    });
}



module.exports.getUserById = function(id, callback){
    Users.findAll({
        where: {id: id}
    });
}
```

My route code, specifically the local passport strategy I'm having trouble with

```
var User = require("../models/users");
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
    function (username, password, done) {
        User.getUserByUsername(username, function (user) {
            if(!user){
                return done(null, false, {message:'Incorrect username'})
            }
        })
        User.comparePassword(password, user.password, function (err, isMatch) {
            if(err) throw err;
            if(isMatch){
                return done(null, user);
            }else{
                return done(null, false, {message: 'Invalid password'});
            }
        })
    }
));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `./models/user` class is exporting a function that takes the `connection` and `DataTypes` as arguments, but you aren't passing them in - the connection should be passed through. You shouldn't need to call `connection.authenticate()`.

```
// new db connection
var connection = new Sequelize(
    schema,
    username,
    password,
    {
      host: host,
      dialect: dialect,
    }
  )
var DataTypes = // define DataTypes

// pass into User
var User = require("../models/users")(connection, DataTypes);
```